# Jquery Simple Ajax POST Request Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have made a test jquery-ajax post script, i am going to implement it in my rating and comment system, but this script is not working.

I have done only simple post request like this.

**test.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: 'test.php',                        
  data: {
        value1:'value1', 
        value2:'value2', 
        value3:'value3', 
        value4:'value4', 
        value5:'value5', 
        value6:'value6', 
        value7:'value7', 
        value8:'value8'
      },                        
  cache: false,              
  success: function(value)          
   {
       alert(value)
   }
});
</script>

<?php 
$value1 =  $_POST['value1'];
$value2 =  $_POST['value2'];
$value3 =  $_POST['value3'];
$value4 =  $_POST['value4'];
$value5 =  $_POST['value5'];
$value6 =  $_POST['value6'];
$value7 =  $_POST['value7'];
$value8 =  $_POST['value8'];

$value = array($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8);
echo json_encode($value);

?>
```

Please see and suggest the ways to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: **Its not working** is not a computer error message. Check console and tell us what's the error.

Comment: Undefined index: value1 and so on and json encode is [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Comment: also i tried replacing `' to "` in jquery, still not working

Comment: Check the header. Is the datas are shown?

Comment: how to check headers. please tell.

Comment: At the top of your php, add - print_r($_POST); exit;

Comment: In chrome, or firefox, there's a header option dev console (firebug in case of firefox). Btw, when you want this even to fire?

Answer (score 0):

you should use different file for ajax call otherwise it will return all html on that page

so i used two files

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST",
 url: 'test.php',                        
 data: {
    value1:'value1', 
    value2:'value2', 
    value3:'value3', 
    value4:'value4', 
    value5:'value5', 
    value6:'value6', 
    value7:'value7', 
    value8:'value8', //value5:'value8' before
  },
 cache: false,              
 dataType: 'json',  //as you are return json from php file so i used dataType json
 success: function(value)          
  {
   $.each(value, function(key, val){
    alert(val);
   });
  }
});
});
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
$value1 =  $_POST['value1'];
 $value2 =  $_POST['value2'];
$value3 =  $_POST['value3'];
$value4 =  $_POST['value4'];
$value5 =  $_POST['value5'];
$value6 =  $_POST['value6'];
$value7 =  $_POST['value7'];
$value8 =  $_POST['value8'];

$value = array($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8);
echo json_encode($value);

?>
```

Comment: *you need to use different file for ajax otherwise....* incorrect statement. You can use the same file for GET, POST, AJAX.

Comment: @itachi yes, we can use GET, POST for ajax call but for this problem it will return full html code on ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `POST` array variables are being set by

```
$value1 =  isset($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
```

Comment: i tried `$value1 =  $_POST['value1'] ? $_POST['value1'] : '1';
$value2 =  $_POST['value2'] ? $_POST['value1'] : '2';
` and so on still not working.

Comment: Where is [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function in your code? Your code still gives error because the `$_POST['value1']` is not yet set, while checking.

Comment: sorry i miss typed i tried like ` $value1 =  isset($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '1';
` and so on, its giving values from php `echo json_encode` but not through jquery `alert(value)`

Comment: Little bit confuse here. Where you are getting the values from php? In the page?

Comment: @TallboY: Have you getting any response? Does `alert` gives nothing in response or Whole page with html content is outputed as response?

Comment: i get this response on the page `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]` and no alerts are triggered.

Comment: @TallboY Is there any error in console? Have you included `jquery` lib in page ?

Comment: this is the error, The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. `on jquery.js (line 2)`

Comment: No idea what is happening there, I have tested your code and it gives me response. The  character encoding error doesn't prevent in alert generation.

Answer (score 0):

To go off what Pragnesh Chauhan mentioned, the problem looks like it's caused by the return not being valid JSON (since your other page code is included invalidating it. There are 2 simple solutions for this.

First, is Pragnesh Chauhan's, put your ajax calls in another file and more sure nothing else is being sent to the browser (including trailing spaces).

Second is to rework your current single file method into something that will work. You'd do this by making it look more like this...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['value1']){ // Checking to see if something was sent to the ajax, you coudl also send another variable is value1 isn't a garuntee
  $value1 =  $_POST['value1'];
  $value2 =  $_POST['value2'];
  $value3 =  $_POST['value3'];
  $value4 =  $_POST['value4'];
  $value5 =  $_POST['value5'];
  $value6 =  $_POST['value6'];
  $value7 =  $_POST['value7'];
  $value8 =  $_POST['value8'];
  $value = array($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8);
  echo json_encode($value);
  exit(); // This tells it to stop so it won't echo out the rest of your page.
}?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: 'test.php',                        
  data: {
    value1:'value1', 
    value2:'value2', 
    value3:'value3', 
    value4:'value4', 
    value5:'value5', 
    value6:'value6', 
    value7:'value7', 
    value8:'value8'
  },                        
  cache: false,              
  success: function(value){
    alert(value)
  }
});
</script>
```

Of course there are other improvements you could make to make the whole thing a little neater but that should get you working at the least.